# Why am I getting the error: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end while downloading multiple images from AWS S3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

## PROBLEM

I am attempting to get multiple files from the AWS S3 bucket. I am using the AWS SDK v3, which makes use of the `GetObjectCommand()` API. This command returns a ReadableStream which I am piping into the `res` object so a single image loads successfully when I make a 'GET' request to my single image endpoint. However, when I create a loop and make multiple calls and attempt to pipe the data to `res`, the whole thing crashes and throws the error:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:668:15)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:680:5)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:661:15)
    at IncomingMessage.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (_http_common.js:139:24)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at ServerResponse.onerror (internal/streams/readable.js:760:14)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:727:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

## WHAT I HAVE TRIED

Since I am using async/await, I tried to have an async callback in the `forEach` loop which makes a call for every single `key` in the `imageKeys` array I send in the 'GET' request, but this doesn't work. I'm not sure how to solve this issue of being able to pipe the multiple data streams to `res` without it closing. Would be great to get some help! NOTE: `getFile()` is a custom function imported in filesController.js.

### EXPRESS CONTROLLERS (filesController.js)

For single file (working):

```js
files.get("/image/:key", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const key = req.params.key;
    // data returned is a ReadableStream. check out Node.js documentation for Readable Streams
    const data = await getFile(carfixBucket, key);
    // a readable stream can pipe data to a writable stream 'res'. 
    // I.E you READ (copy data from) a readable stream and you WRITE (copy data to) a writable stream. 
    // a 
    data.pipe(res);
    // res.status(200).send(data)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

For multiple files(not working):

```js
files.get("/images", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { imageKeys } = req.body; 
    console.log(imageKeys)
    imageKeys.forEach( async (key) => {
      const data = await getFile(carfixBucket, key)
      data.pipe(res)    
    })
    // res.status(200).send("Success")
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
})
```

#### Custom Function

`getFile` is a function I created and exported which accepts the name of the S3 bucket and the key(name) of the file stored in the bucket. It returns a ReadableStream.

```js
const getFile = async (bucketName, key) => {
  const bucketParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
  };
  try {
    // the response returned from Bucket contains a ReadableStream on 'Body' field. to convert to a string if necessary
    const response = await S3.send(new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams));
    return response.Body;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```